# Getting "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server" from amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl

I am trying getting access token but I'm getting this error

> {"error_description":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

```
$code =  $_GET['code'];

$postfields = array(
    'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
    'code'=>$code,
    'redirect_uri='=>'example/myTest.php',
    'client_id'=>'amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// Edit: prior variable $postFields should be $postfields;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 7):

Change `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` from

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

to

`Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: You can also try to `json_encode` your POST array before sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `'token_type' => 'bearer'` to your `$postfields` data.

Here is from Amazon developer documentation:
"Access Token Request ... The type of token returned. Should be bearer."

"Access Token Response: ... unsupported_grant_type   The client specified the wrong token_type."

Comment: I think that parameter refers to the Amazon response. 
They always sent in the response a parameter called token_type.

You do not need it in the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is really old question but in the [official documentation](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-1-request-a-login-with-amazon-access-token) it says valid values are `refresh_token` and `client_credentials`.